# Badge tags padding

Tags: discussion, badges

It is just me or the badge tags have less padding on the left than they used to have? I don't know why but this has been bothering me since yesterday... It doesn't seem right to me... It's a new design or am I just seeing things? Thank you.

Comment: SkeetOverflow compensation, probably, somebody complained before that his profile badge wrapped.